# How can i create auto increment column to my existing column?

Tags: oracle12c

I am working with Oracle 12c in which I have below table structure:-

```
CREATE TABLE patients (
  patient_id Integer NOT NULL,
  customer_id Integer NOT NULL,
  title varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  fname varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  lname varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  dob date NOT NULL,
  is_medical_card NUMBER(1) NOT NULL CHECK (is_medical_card IN (0,1)),
  scheme_number Integer NOT NULL,
  status varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  created_on date NOT NULL,
  last_update_date date NOT NULL,
  consent_flag NUMBER(1) NOT NULL CHECK (consent_flag IN (0,1)),
  relationship varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Where `patient_id` is my primary key so now I want to make it auto increment as well so please let me how can I do this so make it auto increment.

Thanks!

Need to create auto increment to existing column.

Comment: hi, you may create a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `Identities` - Creating a table with an Identity gives you the chance to omit the `ID` values and let Oracle use a sequence on your desired column:

**1. Let's Create the Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE identities (
  id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
  description varchar2(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Table created.

**2. You'll want to create a primary key to ensure uniqueness:**

```
alter table identities add constraint id_pk primary key (ID);
```

Table altered.

**3. Let's insert some data in different ways:**

```
INSERT INTO identities (description)
VALUES('Insert Description omitting ID');
```

1 row created.

```
INSERT INTO identities (id,description)
VALUES(NULL,'Insert with explicit NULL value');
```

1 row created.

**4. Save the work done**

```
commit;
```

Commit complete.

**5. Check the results**

```
select * from identities;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 Insert Description omitting ID
         2 Insert with explicit NULL value
```

As you can see we dind't specify any number for the `ID`, but the `Identity` on the `ID` column did for us

**Note:**  Mind that you can manually insert an `ID`, but this will mess up with the `Identity` as it'll normally do with a standard `Sequence`:

```
INSERT INTO identities (id,description)
VALUES(3,'Manually insert an ID value');

1 row created.


INSERT INTO identities (description)
VALUES('Test Nextval');
INSERT INTO identities (description)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX.ID_PK) violated
```

*This error, because it tries to insert a '3' into the ID that was manually inserted with the statement before.*

**Check the table:**

```
select * from identities;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 Insert Description omitting ID
         2 Insert with explicit NULL value
         3 Manually insert an ID value
```

**Re-Run the "NEXTVAL" insert:**

```
INSERT INTO identities (description)
VALUES('Test Nextval');
```

1 row created.

**Re-Check the table:**

```
select * from identities;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 Insert Description omitting ID
         2 Insert with explicit NULL value
         3 Manually insert an ID value
         4 Test Nextval
```

Hope this Helps.